# AngularJS Save data in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I've a language table, a table with custom tablenames and a table with translations. 
Now I want to insert a new table in all languages. In my Controller I asked for the number of elements in my language table and generate the view:

```
var countLanguages = function () {
   vm.languages = configService.getGlobalLanguageList();
};
```

and the View:

```
<ul ng-repeat="language in vm.languages">

  <h3>{{translations}}</h3>

  <div>
    <label for="EditLanguageLabel" ng-bind="language.label"></label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="translations" id="EditLanguageLabel" required />
  </div>
</ul>
```

But how can I get all fields and save the data in the translationtable with the id of the language and the id of the custom table?
It is not possible to get the $scope.translations in the Controller because every ng-repeat has ist own scope, right?

```
vm.save = function ()
{
   var test = $scope.translations;
};
```

What is the right way to solve this Problem. 
One possible solution could be to load an empty custom table object and add the language. I think there is surely be a better solution.

Comment: use `$parent.translations` instead of `translations`

Comment: Show where `translations` is coming from and where `save()` is being called from. @pankajparkar, `$parent.translations` might work, but it entangles the View, so, if possible I would avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are wanting to change the label of the language. If so all you need to do is set the ng-model of the input to the language variable so:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="language.label" id="EditLanguageLabel" required />
```

this will bind the value of the input to the label of the language and anytime you call get the language.label field it will be the version in the input.

Also ng-repeat doesnt create its own scope anything u access inside of it that is not on the object you create when looping (ex: language.label) is going to be on the scope so you translations is really $scope.translations. If you want each individual language to have its own translations you will need to add the variable to the object array being returns and set the model to:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="language.translations " id="EditLanguageLabel" required />
```

the above code will populate a translations variable on the language object with the value in the input.

Comment: The ng-repeat binds a list of languages. But I want to save each language input field in another array of type translations. I only need the languagelist to know how many languages are in the database. The object i wanna save is of type translation. So my question is, should I generate empty objects of type translation. for example, if I have language de en fr, should I generate three empty objects of type translation and bind it to ng-repeat instead of binding the language array